# How to Identify the package name for specified application(.apk) in android

Tags: android, package

My application contains some list of *.apk files.

I know only the application(example.apk) name.

How to identify this application(example.apk) package name through programmatically.

Is it possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop through installed applications and get package name and path to apk.
Assuming you have the ApplicationInfo for your apk, you can do the same approach as here (without loop).

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
for(ApplicationInfo app : pm.getInstalledApplications(0)) {
    Log.d("PackageList", "package: " + app.packageName + ", sourceDir: " + app.sourceDir);
}
```

Comment: Where we will mentioned the `example.apk` file

Comment: hmm, thought you meant the package name. I'm not aware of how the get the apk name, if I find anything I'll post it here.

Comment: Sorry, My question is how to get the package name for this `example.apk`. I need package name for specific `.apk` file.

Comment: so you want to get the value "example" in your case?

Comment: ohh I see, you want the package name for specific apks file. If you have ten apk, then you could do a for loop in order to print each apk's package name? is that what you want?